# How can I use one Django app to authenticate for other Django apps?

Tags: django, authentication

For reasons I won't bore you with I have different Django installations in different versions, but I want them to delegate authentication to another Django. (I inherited this, and I must admit that I'm knee-deep in it with little background in Django.)

Specifically, I have two Django projects running the 1.4 series and a new one in Django 1.5, using a custom User model. They are physically separate and the 1.4 versions cannot be upgraded or neatened into a tidy single-project, multi-app package. I know it seems weird.

I want the 1.4 apps to get all their user info and authentication from the 1.5 app. It seems like there are a number of ways to do that, ranging on up to something like Oauth, but for bureaucratic reasons, I need the solution that involves the fewest changes to the existing 1.4 apps. Any idea best to accomplis this with a few changes as possible? Seems like there's got to be a straightforward way, but I haven't found it yet.